# `npm audit` is not returning any vulnerabilities, however dependabot is

Tags: github, npm

In order to force devs to update vulnerabilities more often we wanted to add `npm audit` to a pre-push hook. We thought this would cut down on the number of dependabot alerts too.

However, while dependabot is still raising PRs to our repos `npm audit` says everything is fine.

It was my understanding that they both read from the same database now: https://github.blog/2021-10-07-github-advisory-database-now-powers-npm-audit/

Why isn't `npm audit` returning vulnerabilities when dependabot is?